# как решать подобный пример: 3. 13/42 - 4. 6/42?

Tags: математика

как решать подобный пример: 3. 13/42 - 4. 6/42?
Почему вариант 3. 13/42 — 3. 48/42 верен,
а (3 — 4) + 13/42 — 6/42 нет?
И почему тогда в первом варианте решения нужно «догонять» из целой части именно вычитаемое, хотя дробь вычитаемого уже меньше?

Comment: что это вообще такое? почему `4. 6/42` превратилось в `3. 48/42`??? `4. 6` - четыре целых, шесть десятых?

Comment: это программа за 5 класс (ну или 3-4 нормальной школы). сложение дробей.  `3. 13/42` - это такая форма записи 3 и 13/42 (тут нужно рисовать уже). А вот почему один варианта верен, а второй нет - ну так решил учитель, который выучил алгоритм, по которому ученики должны решать. Эти вопросы нужно учителю задавать.

Comment: `4. 6/42 превратилось в 3. 48/42`  ну так логично. 4 и 6/42 это 3 + 1 + 6/42 == 3 + 42/42 + 6/42 == 3 + 48/42. У  меня это в третьем классе рассказывали.

Comment: @KoVadim, ясно, спасибо. Первый раз такую форму записи вижу, но понял теперь, что это.

Comment: да это не особая какая то форма - просто это вопрос для форума математики, где обычно есть соответствующие инструменты форматирования формул.

Comment: Мак, другими словами примерно то же самое, что сказал @KoVadim:  `(3 — 4) + 13/42 — 6/42` разумеется, тоже даст нужный результат. Но вас, вероятно, какому-то конкретному методу работы с дробями учат, и этот вариант под метод не попадает. Вопрос к учителю.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте подробнее посмотрим, что такое 4.6/42

Это четыре целых и еще 6/42. Четыре целых или 4 = 42 * 4 / 42

Т.е. 4.6/42 можно записать как ( 42 * 4 + 6 ) / 42

или `( 42 + 42 + 42 + 42 + 6 ) / 42`

Чтобы решить это пример, надо чтобы у нас было не 4 целых, а три или

( 3 * 42 + 42 + 6 ) / 42 = ( 3 * 42 + 48 ) / 42

Поэтому 4. 6/42 = 3. 48/42

И как вам уже написали в комментариях, оба варианта верны, я просто отвечал на вопрос "почему вариант 3. 13/42 — 3. 48/42 верен"

Ваш вариант я не проверял, но я уверен, что он тоже верен :)

Comment: Полагаю, это не ответ на вопрос. Вопрос-то о том, как правильно применять некий метод, который кто-то рассказал. А вы развернуто пояснили то, что автор и так знал, скорее всего:-)

Comment: @Сергей согласен, можете удалить мой ответ :)